# How assign value to one cell in named range by using xlwings?

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I'm a novice with both Python and xlwings too.
I need to assign a different value for each cell in named range step by step.

xw.Range('Named range').value = [new_cell_values_as_list_of_lists]

This is an example how to assign values to full range `Named range`. This is not what I need for now.

I've searched the xlwings-docs, stackoverflow and so but without any idea...
Ways neither

```
xw.Range(1,'Named range', 22).value = 'yes'
```

nor

```
xw.Range(1, 'Named range', '22').value = 'yes'
```

do not work.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a future version of xlwings, you should be able to use slice notation on a Range directly, but for now, probably the easiest and most efficient method (only one read and write operation) is to read in the whole Range, do manipulations on the Python side and write the whole Range back:

```
values = xw.Range(1, 'Named range').value
values[1][1] = 'yes'
xw.Range(1, 'Named range').value = values
```

Alternatively, depending on your situation, this might also be a possibility:

```
first_col = xw.Range(1, 'Named range').column
first_row = xw.Range(1, 'Named range').row
xw.Range(1, (first_col + 1, first_row + 1)).value = 'yes'
```

Comment: Can you please accept the answer if it solved your problem?